# DateAdd function in excel-vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add no of days to current date field using VB. I am using two different sheets for details. Below is my code-

```
Dim data3 As Variant
Dim data5 As Variant
Dim data6 As Date
Dim duedate As Date

for i = 1 to 10
data3 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Value
data5 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "C").Value
data6 = CDate(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, "C").Value)

If data3 = "Value1" And (data5 = "Value2" Or data5 = "Value3") Then
duedate = DateAdd("d", 5, data6)
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "D").Value = duedate

Else
 'Do nothing

End If
Next i
```

I am not getting desired value. Could you please let me know where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you just trying to add 5 days to the data6?

Comment: Yes, Data6 also contains date.

Comment: Both data5 and data6 are from different sheets

Comment: I tested your macro and it runs just fine for me, it would be easier to not use `DateAdd` since you are already converting it to a date above. Just do `data6 + 5`

Comment: If this is not your desired result, you should post some information of what you are looking for as a result.

Comment: Still not working for me. Could you please suggest another workaround.

Comment: What error are you getting and on what line?

Comment: For example if data3 = value1 and data5 = value3 and data6 = 26-Apr-16
then duedate should be 31/05/2016. I have not set format yet. But I am not any value in sheet where I am storing duedate i.e. Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "D") here, even if the condition is mate with no error

Comment: Are you stepping through your code line by line?

Comment: And is every variable getting the correct variable that you are expecting?

Comment: When you are stepping through your code, after it passes the data3 assignment line, you can hover over data3 to have it show the value. Or you could also pull up the locals window and that will show what each value is, with lots more information as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the current code that I am using, I made a few slight changes, but aren't really of any significance to your code above, besides getting rid of the `DateAdd` part.

```
Sub test()

Dim data3 As Variant
Dim data5 As Variant
Dim data6 As Date
Dim duedate As Date

For i = 1 To 10
    data3 = Sheets(1).Cells(i, "A").Value
    data5 = Sheets(1).Cells(i, "C").Value
    data6 = CDate(Sheets(2).Cells(i, "C").Value)

    If data3 = "Value1" And (data5 = "Value2" Or data5 = "Value3") Then
        duedate = data6 + 5
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, "D").Value = duedate
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```